# jQuery function to add class to one list element on click but remove from the previously clicked element

Tags: jquery

I am creating a messaging app like facebook messenger. when I clicked an image its opened full details page just like a messenger. how I create this?

I want when I click "my name" its hide and "This is my details" will appear.
I used jquery hide and show event. but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demo').click(function() {
    $('#demo2').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">my name</div>
<div id="demo2">This is my details</div>
```

Comment: The OP has made a solid attempt at solving this themselves, and the question is clear and has all relevant code. I'm not seeing any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve this is to put the same class on both elements, while setting the first one as visible in CSS. You can then just call `toggle()` on that class when either of them is clicked, like this:

```js
$('.demo').click(function() {
  $('.demo').toggle("slide");
});
```

```css
.demo { display: none; }
.demo.first { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo first">my name</div>
<div class="demo">This is my details</div>
```